# PrerenderIO not working on my MeteorApp

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, prerender, server-side-rendering

I have an Issue with making PrerenderIO work on my app.
I am running `meteor@1.3.5.1` and `prerender-node` and I have set up this code in my `server/prerenderio.js` like this

```
Meteor.startup( function(){
const prerenderio = Npm.require('prerender-node');
const settings = Meteor.settings.PrerenderIO;

console.log(settings);

if (settings && settings.token && settings.host) {
    console.log('This is true');
    prerenderio.set('prerenderToken', settings.token);
    prerenderio.set('host', settings.host);
    prerenderio.set('protocol', 'http');
    WebApp.rawConnectHandlers.use(prerenderio);
   }
});
```

And my `settings.json` liiks like this

```
{
"PrerenderIO": {
    "token": "wi7DqaiBlaBlaBlaqTGmT",
    "host": "http://locallhost:3000/"
},
"public":{
    "ga": {
        "id": "UA-XXXXXXXXX-1"
    }   
}
}
```

When I start the server on my localhost, I get this on the log

```
Prerender Token: wi7DqaiBlaBlaBlaqTGmT
```

So, I have PrerenderIO's local server running on `port:3033` and when I run `http://localhost:3000/?_escaped_fragment_=`, it takes long and then returns "localhost not found" and logs some error on my meteor server logs.

Also, when I deploy the app to my host, and the visit my prerender.io dashboard I still see the warning that i have not installed my prerender token.

when I visit `http://localhost:3033/http://localhost:3000` I get the cached page without the images

Please **NOTE** i have tried the following packages `dfischer:prerenderio` and `dferber:prerender`but the same thing.

Comment: Hi there. You'll want to regenerate your token since you posted it here. Someone could use that token and cost you money. When you go to `http://localhost:3000/?_escaped_fragment_=` are you seeing a request get sent to your local Prerender server? You should see some console output on the Prerender server if it's sending the request

Comment: Thanks @Prerender.io, That's not my token...changed most part of it. And **No**, I didn't seen anything on the Prerender server but on my meteor, I see some error logs `Error: socket hang up...`

Comment: I think I see an extra `l` in your host of `http://locallhost:3000/`. Also, when you are running your server locally, are you setting the prerenderServiceUrl variable to `http://localhost:3033/`?

Comment: Wow, please let me edit and test again. Thanks. I'll be back soon.

Comment: Just did and same thing. here's a link to the screen caps [link](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AlRX3grZCmUagxUFBqmTtbTa-k51) . Same thin

Comment: @Prerender.io, No, I set the server to `http://localhost:3000/`, What should it be?

Comment: `Experiencing infinite javascript loop. Killing phantomjs...
got 504 in 6522ms for http://localhost:3000/
unable to dispose PhantomJS. Forcing kill...
error force killing phantomjs pid [TypeError: invalid pid]` @Prerender.io, I got this logged when I set `prerenderServiceUrl ` to `http://localhost:3033` and ran `http://localhost:3000/?_escaped_fragment_=` Does this mean anything

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your server, you need to import Meteor to fetch your private settings, you need to import prerenderIO from your node modules and WebApp from meteor/webapp. Setup your config file for prerender like this:

```
import prerenderIO from 'prerender-node';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { WebApp } from 'meteor/webapp';

Meteor.startup(() => {
    const settings = Meteor.settings.private.PrerenderIO;

    if (settings && settings.token && settings.host) {
        prerenderIO.set('prerenderToken', settings.token);
        prerenderIO.set('host', settings.host);
        prerenderIO.set('protocol', 'http');
        WebApp.rawConnectHandlers.use(prerenderIO);
    }
});
```

Also, in your settings, you don't need to include http in your domain string, as you're setting it in the server by calling the protocol method. your host url should just be: localhost:3000